# can epsilon in a epsilon-delta proof rely on the independent variable if it cancels out at the end?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

I’m taking a class in Complex Analysis and trying to prove the same result as found in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129171/prove-that-fz-z2-is-continuous) question.

In the accepted answer, a delta is chosen such that it’s the minimum of two values - one of those values has a $|z_0|$ in it. I was under the impression that delta could not have such variables in it when proving uniform continuity - but the delta is chosen such that the variable is canceled out at the end of the problem.

Is this allowed? I’ve never seen it done before and before I use this on an exam I’d rather know that it’s okay.

Comment: The question you are referring is not proving **uniform** continuity. $z \mapsto z^2$ is only uniformly continuous on bounded subsets of the complex plane. In that (correct) proof of continuity, the dependency of $\delta$ on $z_0$ is fine, but it doesn't yield uniform continuity unless you can bound $\delta$ for the allowable $z_0$s.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for the clarification. In general I can do this then? And can delta depend on an x were I to do this in two dimensions?

Comment: If you are just interested in continuity rather than uniform continuity then the approach in the other question is fine.

Comment: Your title has a befuddling typo. You mean $\delta$, not $\epsilon$. Think about the logic.

Comment: Look at the format of the statement of continuity: $\forall z \forall \epsilon \exists \delta$ [blah blah blah$(z,\epsilon,\delta)$]. Right there it tells you: $\delta$ may depend on $z$ and on $\epsilon$.